# Migrating from Mac to Ubuntu, What will I miss?

Tags: mac, migration

this is my first question (in askubuntu).

I'm about to try Ubuntu for the first time (First time to take it seriously actually).

I love my Mac but don't want to be closed minded, nor closed source ;)

So, if I go ahead with this change, where would you say I would feel the difference?

Pitfalls of Ubuntu compared to Mac? (honestly)

What will I miss the most?

Thanks in advance!!

---

Related: [Difference between mac os and linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11392/difference-between-mac-os-and-linux)

Comment: What kind of Mac you have? Cpu speed / RAM?

Comment: Only YOU know what you'll miss. To some extent it depend what you have/use,and we don't know what that is. All else is mere supposition on our behalf...

Comment: @Pitto Intel Core 2 Duo, 2gb ram, but is more a comparison of OS what I ment by this question.

Comment: @aronchester I did not mean miss like I would miss my family :) I did't want to start a subjective discussion here. I specifics, mac has an app for absolutely anythig (just as an example) in ubuntu will it be harder to get to the right specific software?

Comment: "harder to get to the right specific software?" that will be much easier actually :-) http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/features

Comment: @Stefano I not an expert on the subject (you can see it in myestion ;) ) but I would imagine there are more apps/programs for mac than for Ubuntu, maybe I could agree that Ubuntu has them all together which is very VERY good but mac is launching a "desktop app store" for their new OS so winning some territory there too, would you agree?

Comment: If you just want to try things out, don't forget the option of using something like VirtualBox to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Comment: @Trufa yes I'd agree. I'm just happy that *we were first* (:

Comment: @Stefano Quite true, Mac has been known to move slow sometimes, like the copy paste, multi tasking on smart phones and other but at least there moving. ** cough ** ** cough **

Comment: What I miss when I'm not in Linux is the mark-to-copy function. I can't live without it, so I'm stuck in Linux now...

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve **facts**, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit **opinion**, **debate**, arguments, polling, or **extended discussion**.

Comment: @jrg I agree :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been an *nix user for years and have used Ubuntu for simplicities sake on all my notebooks from the last 3 years or so (everything.. just works!).  My current job provided me with a shiny new MacbookPro when I started just over a year ago, great hardware (almost no complaints), but OSX lasted about a month on it.

To get to the point (sorry about the lenghty diatribe), I've found very FEW issues with the switch, however:

- the setup is *a little* more
  complicated than a similar spec
  Dell/Thinkpad/etc, it's not too hard
  though
- the Mac's greatest asset, by
  far, is the Trackpad, the new
  multitouch driver (check
  www.ubuntuforums.org) are *almost*
  there, but its not quite as silky
  smooth as in OSX

On the good side:

- Compiz is a beautiful, beautiful
  thing (I turn most of the 3D effects
  off), it combines a great way of
  applying keyboard/mouse/gesture
  shortcuts to enhance window
  management and common, often
  laborious tasks with some great
  eyecandy (if you're that way
  inclined).
- 4GB RAM goes a whole lot further in Ubuntu/Gnome than it ever went in MacOSX, I can code, browse, listen, watch, game all without issue.
- Ubuntu's package management, APT, and
  the new Ubuntu Software Centre is
  great for keeping software up to
  date, and allows the installation of
  new apps easily, ironically enough
  its becoming more and more like the
  Apple App Store by the day.

The pitfalls would be the lack of some software like Photoshop (and the Adobe Suite), Microsoft Office (though 2008 was terrible in my experience compared to the Windows version) and many games, but coming from Mac, you probably wouldn't many anyway.

Finally, I'd say, give it a go, at least in a dual boot situation, what have you got to lose?

Comment: Excellent answer @kwiksand !! I agree with everything except: `4GB RAM goes a whole lot further in Ubuntu/Gnome than it ever went in MacOSX, I can code, browse, listen, watch, game all without issue.`maybe the peformance is better in Ubuntu but I'm happy with my 2BG mac right now!

Comment: Like I was saying I knew someone would come in with a more relevant answer. One thing I would say is that In my opinion if you learn how to use Inkscape, the gimp and similar you can be surprised at the results Just ask Doctor Mo head of Ubuntu artists at Deviant art.

Comment: Ok agreed but there is one: I will miss Photoshop although http://www.junauza.com/2010/02/how-to-install-adobe-photoshop-on.html

Comment: You will miss Photoshop only if you are pro user. If you're not using Photoshop advance features, gimp will be enough. Also check Inkscape, Blender. Many news about ubuntu you can read at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk. Welcome to the community!

Comment: One can always multiboot if you need one or two OSX programs. For example, I keep OSX around solely for Lightroom and iTunes, since Apple decided no user-friendly program should ever be able to put music on a 4G iPod (/endRant).

Anyway, Trufa, contrary to your experience, I've found OSX Snow Leopard to be really slow on my '08 4GB MacBook, but Ubuntu zips along. Again, that's just my experience.

Comment: @Trufa Get your happy mac, install ubuntu, then u gonna have a very happy mac. =D See the truth by your eyes.

Answer (score 5):

You will probably miss the comfort of having everything just ready to work and working. Mac OS is a perfect OS, it's beautiful and it just works. But you have to follow Apple's rules. 
Unlike with Ubuntu, you have to pay for most of the best software (although there are some open source or free alternatives for MacOS, too). Unlike Ubuntu, you can't choose your desktop environment. Ok, maybe you don't need to, the original one is quite nice. But it's a compromise between what Apple thinks you need and what you really need. Unlike with Ubuntu, where you can configure almost everything to your needs. You can even configure it to look like a Mac and behave almost like a Mac.
And I'm sure you will not miss:
- The need to buy a new OS each time a major upgrade occurs
- The feeling of having an outdated hardware, Apple is an expert in making you feel that your two or five years old computer is garbage and you have to buy a new one to have the shinny new things that the shiny new cat has to offer. And we are talking about Apple's own hardware! A wonderful and powerfull computer like a last generation PowerMac G5 won't run Snow Leopard! But you can run perfectly the latest (11.10) Ubuntu on a 10 years old power pc properly upgraded with processor and memory.

So, there is not much to miss

Maybe some software which only runs in Mac's, like OmniOutliner.

I'm a big fan of Mac OS but, honestly, with the development and growth of Linux, especially Ubuntu, Mac OS is becoming a useless luxury.

Comment: Good answer. I'm an macosx lover and ubuntu too. I have the sa me opinion

Answer (score 3):

OK I will give a short answer as it is late and I fancy a Haiku

Somethings will not work out of the box.
You will have to find a solution to get it to work.
You will get a huge feeling of satisfaction that you got everything to work and you will now have a deeper understanding of the workings of your computer.
You will feel like you are the master of your computer not it of you

Trufa San

So I'm not being completely serious but really MAC's are perfectly built machines running a perfectly built OS like getting a perfect scale model of Titanic pretty to look at but boring after a while Ubuntu and other linuxses are like a Lego kit for the Titanic or anything else your imagination can stretch to.

I'm sure others will be able to give you a more detailed explanation of the differences but I thought I give you the metaphysical perspective.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks Allan!! You can go Haihuing now! :)

Comment: Confucius say zzzzzzzzzz

Answer (score 2):

You will miss your digital photography apps.

I am actually considering switching to OS X because of that, and I love Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was OSX Services, like the ability to spell check anywhere. Or how most text edit boxes have outline mode, system key bindings and the ability to accept the output of an any service.

Comment: Nice, one thing I love about mac I the ability to drag and drop everywhere, how does this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally agree with other answers, but on ubuntu is very difficult to find software like imovie or finalcut. Oss video editing software are not the same. 
And multitouch experience isn't the same.

Comment: You can try Lives as an alternative. Or OpenShot. But Lives is better.