# Spread only windows of the current application

Tags: effects, window-management

I want the same effect as with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> but for only the selected windows.

Is this possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's *very* easy. Press <kbd>Super</kbd> + *[number]* twice.

For instance, if you want to view all the Nautilus windows you have opened, press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>1</kbd> if Nautilus is the first item on your launcher.

Also, clicking on the icon of an active application that has more than one open window has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Unity source code, this sure is possible, but isn't easy. Unity implements such a view, using the Compiz Scale plugin. First, Unity generates the list of windows of an application and then passes this to Compiz.

So without Unity you can't do this (as for now), since such a feature isn't in Compiz out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to view the code, I hope I learn when someone solves this. For now, it will be [something I'll miss from my mac!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16473/migrating-from-mac-to-ubuntu-what-will-i-miss) :)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes you can.

Install [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Launch CompizConfig Settings Manager and go to **Scale > Bindings > Initiate Window Picker** for window group.

I say theoretically because it [doesn't work for me](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39735/how-do-i-use-initiate-window-picker-for-window-group-in-compiz) (but it does work for others).