# How do I use "Initiate Window Picker for window group" in Compiz?

Tags: compiz, workspace-switcher

I use Unity and Compiz on natty. I have Scale and Scale Addons enabled.

I set
**CompizConfig Settings Manager > Scale > Bindings > Initiate Window Picker for window group** to set my keyboard shortcut for "Initiate Window Picker for window group" to Super+grave (using grab key combo). If I open several gnome-terminal windows and hit Super+grave, nothing happens. Same for empathy, nautilus, gimp, and chromium. I've also tried binding to Super+a.

How does this feature work? What am I doing wrong?

I expect it to work like Application level Expose on a Mac where it lets you switch through all windows from a specific program (all Finder windows or all Chromium windows).

Static Application Switcher's "Next window (group)" feature works as expected.

Comment: That's odd, it works fine for me.

Comment: @Roland: Natty? What shortcut do you use?

Comment: currently I have it set to the right corner for all; but it other shortcuts work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/774059).

If you experience this bug, please select "This bug affects 7 people" and pick "Yes this bug afects me".

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, in the bug report there is a workaround which works for me:

> #### Prabhjot (prabhjotsbhatia) wrote on 2011-11-08:    #8
>
> A workaround:
>
> Hi, I got it working using the "Commands" plugin and "DBus" plugin
>   enabled.
>   I use the following bash script as the command:
>   1. Go to command plugin in the Compiz config settings manager.
>   2. In one of the commands, enter this:
>
> ```
> dbus-send --print-reply --type=method_call \
>     --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/scale/screen0/initiate_key \
>      org.freedesktop.compiz.activate string:'root' int32:`xwininfo -root |
>      grep id: | awk '{ print $4 }'` string:"match" string:$(xprop -id \
>      `xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" | awk '{print $5}'` |
>      grep "WM_CLASS" | cut -d\" -f4 | awk '{print "class=" $1 }')
> ```
>
> In bindings, bind that command to a screen edge or button or
>   keystroke, as you deem fit. Voila!! You have the Scale plugin for the
>   same application class
>
> Note: you need Scale, DBus, Commands plugins enabled. You'd also need
>   to install awk if it isn't installed by default. This works one way
>   and to get out of the scale mode, press Esc or select a window.

For Ubuntu 12.04, add `--reply-timeout=1` to the `dbus-send` command  to avoid being stuck within scale.

Comment: `for Ubuntu 12.04, add --reply-timeout=1` doesn't seem to work for me. It gets stuck everytime the command is called twice, which happen a lot when binded in a corner.

Comment: Using ubuntu 17.04 and see this error -> `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.compiz was not provided by any .service files` in /var/log/Xorg.0.log