# Why isn't it possible to run Mac software?

Tags: mac

I wonder why there isn't any equivalent of Wine for running Mac software on Ubuntu. Thoughts?

Comment: This answer is far too tautological to post as an actual answer so I'll post it here: There is no Wine equivalent for running Mac software because nobody has created a Wine equivalent for running Mac software.

Comment: Ok, and you should answer that on the answer box. I didn't knew that. But anyway, thnx.

Comment: you can run stuff that are universe, like `htop` stuff that only runs in a terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Mac OS applications run natively?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11370/can-mac-os-applications-run-natively)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run OSX applications?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6229/can-i-run-osx-applications)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The best we got was an attempt in 2007-ish called [mac on linux](http://mac-on-linux.sourceforge.net/) as a virtualization tool to run Mac OS.

If there was ever a need to built a wine version for Mac (would that be called mine?) it probably would have been created by someone already. I doubt someone could not make it but I guess that

- there is not enough software that is Mac-only to make it worth while.
- too few Linux users care for Mac software.

Basically there seems no need for it.

1 more issue: you are not allowed to run Mac OS software legally on non Apple hardware. 
Someone who creates it will get sued in an instant and no one will be able to ship it with their OS.

Edit: http://opensource.apple.com/ provides the iOS and Mac OS kernels, which are licensed under free software licenses (it is legal to run on your non-Apple, since otherwise it would be non-free). Basically it is **illegal** to run the Mac OS itself on non-Apple hardware, but **legal** to run software based on Mac OS on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: In contrast, there are lots of Windows-only or Windows and Mac software, and **most** Linux users want to use Windows software.

Comment: In some fields (e.g. graphics, advertising, authors) domain experts insist that the single best tool are (only) available on Mac. So while it's probably true that most *techie* types (who would go ahead and build an emulator) won't care for Mac software in the same way they do for Windows (let's face it: it's mostly about the games!), there *is* a need.

Comment: "there is not enough software that is Mac-only to make it worth while", there may not be many, but some of those few are highly desirable,. Example: [Sequel Pro](https://sequelpro.com/).

Answer (score 11):

Now, there's 'Darling':

- [OS X apps run on Linux with Wine-like emulator for Mac software | Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/08/os-x-apps-run-on-linux-with-wine-like-emulator-for-mac-software/)
- [Project Status | Darling HQ](http://www.darlinghq.org/project-status)

In it's early stages, but it works.

Comment: and the second link is dead ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a translation layer of OS X in linux:

https://www.darlinghq.org/

Unfortunately it can only run terminal programs at the moment and maybe GUI will be in the future.

Comment: 2018... some news here?