# How to install .dmg file to ubuntu

Tags: iso

I'm trying to install a .dmg file to ubuntu 14.04
I was trying to following 
[eHow Link](http://www.ehow.com/how_6674841_install-dmg-file-ubuntu.html)

And a couple of other threads on askubuntu.

The problem i'm facing are so :

1. In the eHow they use something called dmg2dmg. Ubuntu seems to have dmg2img. So I used that instead.
2. After I create the .img file, I try to create a data disk using the .img in brasero. It gives me error saying unsupported format. What am I doing wrong?
3. If I ignore step 2 and just rename .img file to .iso

[Img to ISO Link](http://mikebeach.org/2011/08/28/converting-a-mac-dmg-image-to-iso-in-ubuntu/)

I'm able to mount iso and open the files/folders.

However how to install the .dmg ?? How to install it as an application ???

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of another question AFAIK.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't it possible to run Mac software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50087/why-isnt-it-possible-to-run-mac-software)

Answer (score 5):

What you're following is a link to install Ubuntu on a Mac...

*Probably what you're trying to do is install Mac software on Ubuntu*, which is a bit like trying to run Ubuntu software on Windows...

For more information on running Mac software on Linux, look over there: [Why isn't it possible to run Mac software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50087/why-isnt-it-possible-to-run-mac-software)

Comment: :) .. let me check it out.. Thanks for the help

Comment: The link that I'm following is for installing .dmg files on ubuntu man(not the other way around), [Similar Link as the one I'm following](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-install-a-dmg-file-on-ubuntu) . The link that you had shared is useful. However I feel that the accepted answer in the link you shared just talks about why its difficult to install dmg on ubuntu rather and how. If you could edit your answer with a link that specifically answers my question(even if the solution mentioned doesn't always work) I would accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***Darling*** which is "a translation layer that lets you run macOS software on Linux".
https://www.darlinghq.org/