# How can I run a Mac program on Ubuntu?

Tags: mac, macosx, emulation

Occasionally I would like to run a program made for Mac on Ubuntu (example: [Dash](http://kapeli.com/dash)). What software can I use to run a single Mac program, like I'm able to do with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/)?

I like the convenience of [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/) - sometimes you need specific settings or specific Wine version to run your Windows program, and PlayOnLinux makes it easy to provide this on per-program basis. Then you can make a desktop icon that looks and works as a native application.

Is there anything similar I can use for Mac programs in Ubuntu?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6229/can-i-run-osx-applications

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks, didn't see this. Is there a way to solicit newer answers for this question, short of asking it again? The answers on  the question you linked to are old, and I hope that the situation with Mac emulation has changed for the better, but this question hasn't got the attention lately.