# How can I install software (made for Mac OS) in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, macosx

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in my HP Compaq 6910P notebook. Now I want to use Mac based software, since I can use Windows based software through Wine.

But I do not know how to install and run Mac based application in my Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is this software ?

Comment: This question has already been asked [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6229/can-i-run-osx-applications). Please refer to it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wine can run windows applications, but there is no robust equivalent allowing Mac applications to run on Linux. Some projects that try to change this are:

1. [Mac-on-Linux](http://mac-on-linux.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Darling](https://www.darlinghq.org/)
3. http://opensource.apple.com/ - not an 'emulator' but provides the iOS/OSX kernels, licensed under free software licenses

Answer (score 1):

There aren't really any ways to run **Mac-specific** apps on Linux. You can run a large number of cross-platform apps; Gimp and MacVim come to mind. But if you *must* run mac apps, the most reliable answer is to buy a Mac. You'll always have the latest versions and you can also run any other OS using Fusion, Virtual Box or Parallels.

The second best option is to run Hackintosh (aka, [OSx86](http://www.osx86project.org)). I tried this years ago and had mixed results. You had to be willing to spend a bit of time tuning/tweaking and making sure your kext files worked. I know people who've done it, but I lacked the patience.